# Resolving Promises Asynchronously in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

My code:

```
$q(function (resolve) {
    var imageUploadResults = [];
    fileUploadService.uploadImage($scope.filesUpload, "/api/mailbox/uploadAttachFile", function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        imageUploadResults.push(result.LocalFilePath);
    });
    $scope.mail.Files = imageUploadResults;
    resolve($scope.mail);
}).then(function (mail) {
    console.log(mail);
    apiService.post("/api/mailbox/sendMail", mail, sendMailSucceed, sendMailFailed);
});
```

**Expect:**
I want to add value to *mail.Files* finish,then call *apiService.post()*

**Actual:**
But it execute *apiService.post()* with *mail.Files* value is [].
When *apiService.post()* execute finish *mail.Files* return value.length > 0.

Comment: You are immediately resolving your promise.. you should be resolving the promise inside the callback of your .uploadImage() call

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing exactly which library you are actually using, it seems clear to me that `fileUploadService.uploadImage()` is asynchronous.

The function that you give as an argument is a callback and there is no guarantee that it would be executed "on time". In your case the path is added to `imageUploadResults` after the moment where you set `$scope.mail.Files`.

you should set `$scope.mail.Files` and call `resolve` in your callback function.

```
$q(function (resolve) {
    var imageUploadResults = [];
    fileUploadService.uploadImage($scope.filesUpload, "/api/mailbox/uploadAttachFile", function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        imageUploadResults.push(result.LocalFilePath);
        $scope.mail.Files = imageUploadResults;
        resolve($scope.mail);
    });
}).then(function (mail) {
    console.log(mail);
    apiService.post("/api/mailbox/sendMail", mail, sendMailSucceed, sendMailFailed);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assigned `$scope.mail.Files = imageUploadResults;` and resolved `resolve($scope.mail);` there are no guarantee that `fileUploadService.uploadImage` finished request and saved `imageUploadResults.push(result.LocalFilePath);`

Possible solution is to add `resolve($scope.mail);` right after `imageUploadResults.push(result.LocalFilePath);` in function passed to `fileUploadService.uploadImage`

Answer (score -1):

Your .then function should be using  $scope.mail and not mail as a parameter? so as of  right now you're sending an empty object through instead of the mail object.